# IOS/Storyboard: Images Disappear from identity inspector after lengthy Redos but still visible in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, undo

After undoing a long sequence of changes in Storyboard to reverse accidentally replacing a complex view with a new one, while the storyboard continues to show images, when you build the product, the images are not visible.

Upon inspection of the images in the identity inspector, the image names are blank--although they still show in the storyboard.  Unfortunately, I don't remember the names of all these images so would like to avoid having to re-specify them.  The undoing did not involve the images specifically.  However, the problem was I accidentally replaced the superview with a blank view and had to undo this change to restore the original view--only, it appears, with some corruption.

Short of figuring out the names of the images and re-entering them, is there anything else I can try?  Should I clean project or could that make things worse?

Wondering if anyone has had experience with images disappearing from identity inspector after storyboard undos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning the project. If it doesn't resolve, worse it won't be either.